Excel Macro user defined to decrypt a string that was encrypted with AES-256 from mysql?
I would like to have a macro user defined function to decrypt a column of string in excel that was encrypted with AES-256. Anyone can help me with this?
I have tried googling and some code but somehow it doesn't work.
' Define the AES key and other constants
Const KEY_SIZE As Integer = 32 ' AES-256 key size (32 bytes)
Const BLOCK_SIZE As Integer = 16 ' AES block size (16 bytes)

' Dummy placeholder functions for AES operations
' You'll need to implement these functions according to AES standards
Function KeyExpansion(key As String) As Variant
    ' Implement key expansion for AES-256 here
End Function

Function InvSubBytes(state As Variant) As Variant
    ' Implement Inverse SubBytes operation here
End Function

Function InvShiftRows(state As Variant) As Variant
    ' Implement Inverse ShiftRows operation here
End Function

Function InvMixColumns(state As Variant) As Variant
    ' Implement Inverse MixColumns operation here
End Function

Function AddRoundKey(state As Variant, roundKey As Variant) As Variant
    ' Implement AddRoundKey operation here
End Function

Function AES256Decrypt(cipherText As String, key As String) As String
    Dim state(BLOCK_SIZE - 1) As Byte
    Dim roundKeys() As Byte
    Dim decryptedText As String
   
    ' Convert cipherText and key from hex string to byte array
    ' Add your conversion code here
   
    ' Key expansion
    roundKeys = KeyExpansion(key)
   
    ' Decryption process
    ' Implement AES decryption rounds here
    ' This involves Inverse SubBytes, Inverse ShiftRows, Inverse MixColumns, and AddRoundKey

    ' Convert the decrypted state back to a string
    ' Add your conversion code here

    AES256Decrypt = decryptedText
End Function

Sub DecryptCell(cellAddress As String, key As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim encryptedText As String
    Dim decryptedText As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Or specify your worksheet

    ' Get the encrypted value from the cell
    encryptedText = ws.Range(cellAddress).Value

    ' Decrypt the cell value
    decryptedText = AES256Decrypt(encryptedText, key)

    ' Update the cell with the decrypted value
    ws.Range(cellAddress).Value = decryptedText
End Sub

Sub TestDecryption()
    Dim key As String
    key = "A0B1C2D3E4F50617283940566778899A0B1C2D3E4F50617283940566778899A0B1C2D3E4F506172" ' Replace with your actual 256-bit key in hexadecimal format

    ' Decrypt cell A1 on the active sheet
    DecryptCell "A1", key
End Sub


And what does not work? The code seems to contain only the rough structure without any algorithm or function.

Thanks @Shrotter, yeah, which part should i add the algorithm? I am not sure which part i need to add the code at.

Just guessing here, but it's probably the parts that have the comment ' Add your conversion code here and the 'Implement Inverse xxxxxx operation here

@DarrenBartrup-Cook thanks alot.. unfortunately I do not know what to add the algorithm here
